# How can I add a where exists statement in this "group by" mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns the range of a value within groups in the table.

Now I want to check for every group if a value "results" occurs in column "pages", and only if the statements holds true, return the row.

A example of the table structure:

```
   ID  pages    start_time
    1   splash   12
    1   view     14
    1   comments 16
    1   results  18
    2   splash   1
    2   view     13
    2   comments 14
    2   comments 15
    3   test     2
    3   splash   3
    3   results  35
    3   view     26
```

From this example, the following should be returned:

```
   ID   time_range
    1    6
    3    33
```

because ID=2 doesn't have row "results" in column pages.

I have the following query, but don't get the additional condition to work.

```
SELECT MAX(start_time)-MIN(start_time) 
FROM mytable 
WHERE country="United States"
AND (here should come the if-results-in-pages-exists statements) 
GROUP BY my_id;
```

How can I add this condition properly?

Comment: Can you please provide a few sample rows in your table for the relevant columns and a sample of the output you expect after running the query? That would make it a lot more clear.

Comment: @EmanuelLainas I added an example, any ideas how to do this?

Comment: maybe interesting? as something to start with?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/142af/19

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(start_time)-MIN(start_time) 
FROM mytable
WHERE country="United States" 
AND pages like '%results%'
GROUP BY my_id;
```

Alternatively

```
SELECT MAX(start_time)-MIN(start_time) 
FROM mytable
WHERE country="United States" 
AND my_id IN (select distinct my_id from mytable where pages like '%results%')
GROUP BY my_id;
```

Comment: How do you know which result belongs to which my_id

Comment: The first query is sound. The second not so, and it will perform worse - I recommend deleting it from your answer.

Comment: thanks, but these solutions would only return the rows that contain "results". However, I want the whole group of rows with the ID that also contains "results", see my example above. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Hi user, the second query will do as u need

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version:

```
SELECT 
  A.`id`,
  MAX(B.`start_time`) - MIN(B.`start_time`)
 FROM `whenpages` A
 LEFT JOIN `whenpages` B ON
   A.`id` = B.`id`
 WHERE 
   A.`pages` = 'results'
 GROUP BY
   A.`id`
```

Replace `A.pages =` with `A.pages LIKE` if needed.